# Using node modules in testacular

Tags: node.js, angularjs, karma-runner

Is it possible to 'require' NodeJS modules in Jasmine tests which run under Testacular (to test AngularJS end-to-end scenarios)?

Background:

I'm building a NodeJS service which delivers an AngularJS frontend and provides a number of services to feed it data. One feature is to present a list of files delivered from the Node service to an Angular controller. These files are collected from a backend FTP server.

For my end-to-end angular scenario tests, which I run in Testacular, I would like to add sample files to a local FTP server's directory during the running of the Jasmine tests.
Ideally, I would like to require the NodeJS 'fs' module do write these files but I haven't seen any examples of this kind of test configuration before.

I'm not sure whether the RequireJS adapters are suitable for this requirement.
Any ideas?